# Make htaccess accept domain.com and www.domain.com

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

How to modify this htaccess so that it will allow www.domain.com and domain.com. Now when i give www.domain.com, it changes it to domain.com

```
Options -Indexes
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^$ website/index.php [L]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/website%{REQUEST_URI} -f
RewriteRule .* website/$0 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* website/index.php?q=$0 [QSA]
```

Sorry, dont have much knowledge with htaccess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just take out first 301 rules that strips `www`:

```
Options -Indexes
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^$ website/index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/website%{REQUEST_URI} -f
RewriteRule .* website/$0 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* website/index.php?q=$0 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Thx for your reply, but it is still changing the url from www.domain.com to domain.com.

Comment: Can you try this in a new browser to avoid caching issues.

Comment: Great to know it worked out. Yes 301 statuses are aggressively cached by the browsers.